# Find domain of funcition

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Do you have any advice on how to find domain of function 
$f(y)=\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{(16-x^2)}$ ?
Please give me some advice about how to do it in general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin(x)$ must be positive, so $x\in[0+2k\pi,\pi /2+2k\pi]$ and $(16-x^2)$ must be positive to so $x \in [-4,4]$.

Then take the intersection $x\in [0+2k\pi,\pi /2+2k\pi] \cap [-4,4]=[0,\pi /2]$

Comment: How is that an answer on how to do it ''in general''?

Comment: How do you take the intersection?

Comment: $[0+2k\pi,\pi /2+2k\pi]=...[-2\pi,\pi/2-2\pi]\cup[0,\pi/2]\cup[2\pi,\pi/2+2\pi]...\cap[-4,4]$ and the only possible intersection is  $[0,\pi/2]$ as the other are less than $-4$ or greater than $4$

Answer (score 2):

You have some square roots. Is $\sqrt{x}$ defined everywhere?

The inside of a square root is defined for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Real numbers only.

Comment: So consider x=-1.

Comment: I obviously considered you were working on $\mathbb{R}$ and not $\mathbb{C}$.